# Vertically align a div for responsive template

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

How can I make the text inside the div: "grid2" and "section2" vertical align in the middle?

Is this an issue within my HTML or does my problem occurs within the css? Could anyone point me into the right direction?

I have tried looking at other questions but the answers don't bring me further.

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
 <div id="template">  
  <div class="grid2">
   <div class="section2">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">New 2014 Model</h2>
    <p>Latest model forced air (with a fan) fully automatic 48 egg incubator.</p>
    <p>This new design uses a sophisticated program for automated hatching process that    produces one of the highest hatching rates of any model, yet is incredibly easy to use.  Perfect for small hatchers, self sufficient households, or families incubating in the backyard.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--responsive-->
```

**My CSS:**

```
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
} 
.clear {
clear:both;
} 
#background {
background-color:#FFFFFF; 
background-position:top;
width:100%;
max-width:1000px;
margin:auto;
} 
#template {
padding:10px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
} 
.responsive {
width:100%;
} 
.grid2 {
float: left;
width:50%;
min-width:280px;
}
.grid3 {
float: left;
width:33.3%;
min-width:280px;
} 
.grid4 {
float: left;
width:16.66%;
min-width:160px;
} 
.section4 {
padding:1px;
} 
.section3 {
padding:5px;
} 
.section2 {
padding:10px;
}
.shrinkable {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px; 
text-align:center;
} 
.shrinkable img {
width:60%;
height: auto;
} 
.shrinkable p {
text-align:center;
} 
.column {
display:block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
} 
.column:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
} 
.box {
width: 32.2%;
} 
.row:before,.row:after {
content:"";
display:table;
} 
.row:after {
clear:both;
}
```

**Here is** [the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Ynm/)

Comment: Please try to add a jsfiddle, and give your code some tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This will center the text verticaly and horizontally

```
.grid2 {height: 100%; display:table; text-align: center}
.section2 {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}
```

Comment: A modified version of this works great.`.grid2 {float: left;width:50%;min-width:280px; height: 100%; display:table;} .section2 {padding:10px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}` but now has large gaps above and below each Div. How to fix?

Comment: After some trial and error I figured out it was the `height: 100%;` that was causing the problem. But without it the solution does not work. This is responsive so I can't have a fixed height either. Still searching for solution and will update here if I find.

Answer (score 0):

Add either a CSS-Class

```
p {
   text-align: center;
}
```

or add inline style like you did in the headline:

```
<p style="text-align: center;>Latest model forced air (with a fan) fully automatic 48 egg incubator.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;>This new design uses a sophisticated program for automated hatching process that produces one of the highest hatching rates of any model, yet is incredibly easy to use. Perfect for small hatchers, self sufficient households, or families incubating in the backyard.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and see.

```
.grid2  {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}
.section2   {clear:both; height:240px; position:relative;}
```

Comment: In a responsive template you shouldn't be setting heights on elements.

Answer (score -1):

With it being responsive I find that the best method is not rely on css because there shouldn't be any set heights if it is truly responsive.

The best way is to use jquery to find the height of the parent div, and then align the required text/image/div based on that value. This can be calculated using jquery resize function, meaning when the dimensions change it remains centered.

Something along the lines of:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var changeheight = $('.parentdiv').height() / 2;
   $('.div').css('margin-top', changeheight)
});
```

But you would need to factor the size of the div you are centering into the calculation.